# Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.OutputFilter' or one of its dependencies opening index.html in browser from VS2013

Tags: angularjs, kentico

This problem occurs when my source files are on my E drive, but not when they are in my C:  MyDocuments folder.

I am working through Deborah Kurata's AngulaJS Line of Business Applications course on Pluralsight.

I have the following Index.html open in VS2013

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Acme Product Management</title>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I right click the code and select

```
view in browser (Chrome)
```

I get the following error

This seems to relate to Kentico, which I do have installed.

How do I fix it?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.OutputFilter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.OutputFilter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'CMS.OutputFilter' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.OutputFilter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +39
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +37
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +65
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.OutputFilter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +348
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +19
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +39
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +42
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +158
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +950
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.OutputFilter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9931916
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249
```

Answer (score 0):

Web.config files are like CSS files, they inherit one another.  So if your AngularJS website is an application below your main Kentico site within IIS, it's inheriting those values in the web.config file of the Kentico site.  In the web.config file of the AngularJS site, you need to add

```
  <remove name="XHtmlModule"/>
```

In the `<system.webServer><modules>` node.  This will tell your AngularJS project to not inherit that module.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "an application below your main Kentico site"  I am simply opening the index.html in VS2013, right clicking the code and selecting view in browser.  I don't have a project with a web.config file.

Comment: I typically setup the websites I'm developing within IIS.  What I mean by an application below your main Kentico site is if your site is setup with IIS then your AngularJS project would be an application running in the same website as Kentico but as a separate application.  This could also mean if you're using IIS Express (Visual Studio default), the Kentico site could be the main one and your AngularJS project could be a sub app.  You can check by selecting the main website in Visual Studio and viewing the properties.  It will show you the URL and port, if applicable.

Comment: Oh dear, can you explain what you mean by selecting the main website in Visual Studio?  I have not set up my AngularJS website inside IIS.  All I am doing is opening an index.html file in VS2013, right clicking the code and selecting run in browser.